# Rails 5.1.4: Third-party assets in /vendor wont show in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, amcharts

I am trying to run a simple rails (-v 5.1.4) application which implements one of the samples that ship with the amcharts library.

Here's what **did** work:

- create `/app/assets/javascripts/amcharts` folder
- copy third party content to `/app/assets/javascripts/amcharts`
- add `//= require amcharts` to `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

I run the rails server and the graph is displayed as expected from watching the original stand-alone html view. Therefore I assume the edited code is working correctly.

Here's what **did not** work:

- create `/vendor/assets(/javascripts)/amcharts` folder
- copy third party content to `/vendor/assets(/javascripts)/amcharts`
- add `//= require amcharts` to `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`
- add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor/assets(/javascripts)/amcharts')` to `config/application.rb`
- add relative paths `../../../vendor/assets(/javascripts)/amcharts/$name$.js` to `app/assets/application.js`

When I run the rails server no error is given but the application displays an blank white page instead of the graph, the source-code of the page shows the code of my view-file as expected.

Since my respective view is called `amcharts.html.erb` I have a `amcharts.coffee`-file in my `app/assets/javascripts/`-folder. Could it be sprockets falsely assumes that's the file it needs?

Also I wonder what the `app/config/manifest.js` is for. All manifest related changes seem to be made in the `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file anyways...

EDIT: An shortened version of my view-file `app/views/amcharts/index.html.erb` (modified code of the samples from amcharts lib)

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
var chartData = [ { $data } ];
AmCharts.ready(function () { 
  chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  $AmCharts.funs
  chart.write("chartdiv");
});
</script>
```

Comment: did you try this way: https://rails-assets.org/#/components/amcharts3

Comment: @WasifHossain Thanks for sharing that gem. I tried other gems before, but they weren't compatibly. This one I was able to install. But sadly the problem still remains. I'll provide the first lines of my view-file code in the original post. Maybe there's an issue I didn't realize. Also I fear I'd run into the same trouble the next time I'll have to add 3rd party content.

Comment: i would suggest not to fear at all, rather go ahead with boldness :) personally I found rails-assets to help maintain 3rd party assets in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what files/directories you copied to `vendor/assets/javascripts`? Also, do you need to bundle the library with your application? It might be easier just to use the CDN version at `https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js`.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for your advice. Gladly I got some help. After adding a gem or two and fixing the application.js it finally worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the opportunity to share my files with a professional and he fixed the problem. The way to go was:

- Install gems 'amcharts-rails', 'rails-assets-amcharts3'
- add `//= require amcharts3`, `//= require amcharts3/serial` to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

I still wonder how to include third-party-content from vendor/assets. But since the whole thing is working now without files in wrong folders, I'll mark this as answered. Thanks to everybody who tried to help!

Answer (score -1):

Put the JS package directly under `vendor/assets`, not in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. For example, add the `/vendor/assets/amcharts/amcharts.js` library to your application via `//= require amcharts`.

For a more concrete example, here's how I've structured including the DataTables library in a Rails 5 application:

```
vendor/assets/DataTables-1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js
vendor/assets/DataTables-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js
vendor/assets/DataTables-1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css
```

(Note the folder hierarchy below `vendor/assets` is exactly what the DataTables package provides.)

application.css:

```
/*
 *= css/dataTables.bootstrap4
 */
```

application.js:

```
//= require js/jquery.dataTables
//= require js/dataTables.bootstrap4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I copied the library files to vendor/assets/amcharts and added `//= require amcharts/amcharts` and `//= require amcharts/serial` to application.js. Also i tried `//= require amcharts`. No luck.

Comment: Is this a typo? `//= require amcharts` (edit: ah I didn't have the right name of the library your're trying to use, best of luck)